# Recursive and non-recursive prompt together in Yeoman

Tags: recursion, yeoman

I'm building a Yeoman generator, and have some prompts for the user, I use a prompt queue like this:

```
var prompts = [{
  name: 'name',
  message: 'What is the name of this module?'
},{
  name: 'desc',
  message: 'Describe your module:'
}];

this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
  this.name = props.name;
  this.desc = props.desc;

  done();
}.bind(this));
```

But how can I add a recursive question to this prompt? I want to ask the user for dependencies, and let them fill in a name, press enter, fill in another name, until they press enter with a blank answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts i found a solution that works:

```
var dependencies = [];
var dependency = function(self) {
  var dep_quest = {
    name: "dependency",
    message: "Need any dependencies? (Leave blank to continue)"
  };
  self.prompt([dep_quest], function(props)
    if (props.dependency !== '') {
      dependencies.push(props.dependency);
      dependency(self);
    }
    else {
      self.dependencies = dependencies;
      done();
    }
  });
}

this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
  this.name = props.name;
  this. desc = props.desc;

  dependency(self);
}.bind(this));
```

After the regular questions i call the dependency function that asks one question again and again until a blank answer is provided. Then it calls the `done()` function.